# Javascript dataTable entry type in .net core

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have this javascript code:

```
  dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/books/getall/",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "author", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "isbn", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "IdCategory", "width": "20%" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="text-center">
                        <a href="/Books/Upsert?id=${data}" class='btn btn-success text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'>
                            Edit
                        </a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a class='btn btn-danger text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'
                            onclick=Delete('/books/Delete?id='+${data})>
                            Delete
                        </a>
                        </div>`;
                }, "width": "20%"
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "no data found"
        },
        "width": "100%"
    });
```

if remove this line:

```
  { "data": "IdCategory", "width": "20%" },
```

the app works.

If, in the place of "IdCategory", I write "isbn" the code works.

I suspect that the issue depends on the type, because "IdCategory" is integer and not text.

There is a way to solve on the Javascript side? Or I need to convert the data on the c# side?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe your response has idCategory not IdCategory. check your /books/getall response in developer console

Comment: the field name is IdCategory and json at c# side return data correctly without crash.

Comment: as @mehmetx mentioned the response data is idCategory.(see the small i) and in your js you have mentioned the column as capital "I". Change it to small and it will work.

Comment: Thank you at all ! I confirm that you have right, but I ask how is possible if in the model I have:   public int IdCategory { get; set; }

Comment: your serializer (JsonConvert or another) makes small the first letter of the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to (with small i)

```
{ "data": "idCategory", "width": "20%" },
```